# Can someone tell me how the if statement is missing up my robot?

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide

This code is supposed to make a robot drive forward until it comes with 8 inches of an object. Depending on which of the three sensors detects the object the robot will turn left or right. I am issued with the code so I decided to start over testing each part as I go along. The commoned out part of the code is the part that makes the robot turn left when the right sensor detects an object. With it, out commented out the robot moves forward at the speed I coded, but when the commented out part is uncommented the robot moves in a circle with small pauses in between(even with the 3-second delay commented out). Can someone tell me what is wrong and how can I fix it?

```
#include<SoftwareSerial.h> // Import the serial Library
#include <Wire.h>
#include <Adafruit_MotorShield.h>
#include "utility/Adafruit_MS_PWMServoDriver.h"

// Create the motor shield object with the default I2C address
Adafruit_MotorShield AFMS = Adafruit_MotorShield();
// Select which 'port' M1, M2, M3 or M4. In this case, M1

Adafruit_DCMotor *FL= AFMS.getMotor(1); //Front left motor

Adafruit_DCMotor *FR= AFMS.getMotor(4); //Front right motor
int left_trig = 8;
int left_echo = 9;

int mid_trig = 5;
int mid_echo = 6;

int right_trig = 3;
int right_echo = 4;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
AFMS.begin();  // create with the default frequency 1.6KHz

  //This establishes the sensors as inputs and outputs
 pinMode(left_trig,OUTPUT);   
  pinMode(left_echo,INPUT);

  pinMode (mid_trig,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(mid_echo,INPUT);

  pinMode (right_trig,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(right_echo,INPUT);

  FL->setSpeed(150);
  FL->run(FORWARD);
  FL->run(RELEASE);
  FR->setSpeed(150);
  FR->run(BACKWARD);
  FR->run(RELEASE);
}

void loop() {
  long duration1, duration2, duration3, inches1, inches2, inches3;

   digitalWrite(left_trig, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(left_trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  duration1 = pulseIn(left_echo,HIGH);


 // pinMode (mid_trig,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(mid_trig, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(mid_trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
    duration2 = pulseIn(mid_echo, HIGH);

//  pinMode (right_trig,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(right_trig, LOW); 
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(right_trig, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10);
   duration3 = pulseIn(right_echo, HIGH);

    // convert the time into inches
  inches1 = microsecondsToInches(duration1);
  inches2 = microsecondsToInches(duration2);
  inches3 = microsecondsToInches(duration3);

  Serial.print(inches1);
  Serial.print("in,\t");
    Serial.print(inches2);
  Serial.print("in,\t");
    Serial.print(inches3);
  Serial.print("in");
  Serial.println();
delay(300);

FL->setSpeed(150);
  FL->run(FORWARD);
  FR->setSpeed(150);
  FR->run(BACKWARD);

//  if(inches1<=8)
//{
//FL->setSpeed(150);
//  FL->run(FORWARD);
//  FR->setSpeed(150);
//  FR->run(FORWARD);
//
//}
}
long microsecondsToInches(long microseconds) {
  return microseconds / 74 / 2;
}
```

Comment: Please post the actual code, not screenshots!

Comment: tried but it keeps telling me it's not formatted despite the fact I followed the format they gave me.

Comment: What does your serial monitor say the value of inches1 is?

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem actually is - is `inches1` calculated correctly, for instance, or does it always detect an object? Please explain more clearly.

Comment: The sensor does calculate correctly when I put something in front of it, but every now and then you'll get a really high number.

Answer (score 0):

With that if statement and block uncommented if inches1 is ever less than or equal to 8 the code will come through loop and first hit the code to run forwards and then the if statement and code to turn and then repeat, go straight no wait turn no wait go straight no wait turn.

The code above that if statement that tells your bot to go forward needs to also be conditional.  It should only be allowed to run when there is no object detected.  There are many ways to accomplish that.  It could be that you have an if - else if for each sensor and then the go forward code is in the else at the end if none of them trip.  Or you could make the first condition that all the distances are greater than some threshold.